# My localStorage value is saving as null accross my webpages and i cant figure out why

Tags: javascript, local-storage

For one of my JavaScript assignments
I need to save a job reference number via local storage from one web page and have it appear on another.
however i set the item in local storage, and change webpages, the value gets returned as null (using an alert box just to test)
help would be much appreciated as i cannot understand why it wont store the data.
I have tested that the number is actually saving by putting an alert in the retrieveCloudJRN function as alert (localStorage.getItem('clJRN') and it shows CAD12

**EDIT: Ive realised that the code and localstorage works fine on chrome, but not on firefox(which is the requirement for the assignment)**

**minimal reproducable example html page 1**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="mre.js"> </script>
    <title>mre</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Mre test </h1>
    <p id = "jrn" >JRN CAD12</p>
    <p id="butt"> next page </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**minimal reproducable example html page 2**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="mre.js"> </script>
    <title>mrenew</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> MRE test page 2 </h1>
        <p id="clickme"> click here to open alert </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**minimal reproducable example js page**

```
function retrieveJRN(){
    var strJRN = document.getElementById("jrn").textContent;
    var JRN= strJRN.substring(4);
    localStorage.setItem('clJRN', JRN);
    alert (JRN);
}
function changewb(){
    window.location.href ="mrenew.html";
}
function clicktochange(){
   var button = document.getElementById("butt");
   button.onclick= changewb;
}
function pasteCloud (){
    alert (localStorage.getItem('clJRN'));
}
function init(){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('mre.html') > -1) {
    var jrn = document.getElementById("jrn");
    jrn.onclick=retrieveJRN;
    clicktochange();
    }
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('mrenew.html') > -1){
    var clickme = document.getElementById("clickme");
    clickme.onclick = pasteCloud;
    }
}
window.onload=init;
```

Comment: *"why it wont store the data [...] the number is actually saving"* - It's not clear to me what isn't working then.  You've testing that it's working, but are observing that it isn't working?  Can you provide a [mcve] of two simple pages which demonstrate the problem, storing a value on one page then navigating to the next page and reading the value?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion David, when i put an alert(localStorage.getItem('clJRN') on the initial web page in the same function (retrieveCloudJRN()) after storing it in local storage it comes up showing CAD12, however after navigating to the next page, and once again using an alert (localStorage.getItem('clJRN') it says Null

Comment: In my case in the past I solved the same problem using this approach: you can try to use a simple framework like sveltekit and then use stores to share data between multiple pages https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores . but can seem over-engineered at the start but it is worth it (at least in my case... I chose sveltekit over react or any other library because it was the only one where I can just copy and paste my codebase and expect to work right away) NOTE: paste all html, js code inside a pages/+page.svelte, then write the store in a javascript file inside lib/ and export, and use it

Comment: Thanks laaouatni, unfortunately  we are not allowed to use any frameworks or libraries in this assigment

Comment: @OmarAlangurli: There's more happening in this code than just reading and writing local storage values.  How have you confirmed in your debugging that the value isn't simply being over-written by the code between the time that you first write it and the time that you read it?  A [mcve] is crucial here.

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas: An entire framework isn't necessary just to use `localStorage`, as it's [natively part of web browsers and easily accessible with plain JavaScript code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: @David this is what I said, it isn't right approach, is over-engineered but it helps if you have to pass data between routes. because from what I know localstorage by default isn't accessed by 2+ pages. `example.com/foo` and `example.com/bar` doesn't have the same local storage, when in a framework is more easier to share things between. is still a bad approach and over complexed, I just tell my experience and what solved it for me :) also, OP already told me that we are not allowed to use any frameworks or libraries in this assignment, so there arent any pros to using a framework in this case

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas: *"from what I know localstorage by default isn't accessed by two+ pages. example.com/foo and example.com/bar doesn't have the same local storage"* - You are mistaken.  Two pages from the same origin have access to the same `localStorage`.  This is [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and easily testable.  It's great that you have a favorite framework that you enjoy using (I have a few as well), but it's not a golden hammer.

Comment: @David sorry, if it is like this,  fantastic  , I will explore more about that too :) thanks (yeah I am started directly on a framework, on little things that can be done with only js vanilla, stupid me) thanks, have a nice day!

Comment: @David, okay the MRE is done, i have edited the post to reflect this. Ive actually figured out that when i run the page on chrome, the local storage works, but when i run it on firefox it doesnt, any idea what i can do about that?

Comment: @OmarAlangurli "minimal reproducible example" does not mean "dump all your application code on us". It needs to be ***minimal***, the shortest code that *shows the problem*. Strip it down, and make sure you check the stripped down version. We have that rule for two reasons: 1. it makes it much easier to read your code to help you and 2. often in the course of creating it you'll figure out how to solve your own problem.

Comment: @jared Smith that was my stripped down code... i made the smallest possible HTML and JS i could to recreate the issue....i went from  ~500 lines of code in my original to ~50 im not sure how much further you want me to strip it

Comment: @OmarAlangurli I've removed my downvote... but please remove the original wall o'code and leave just the MRE. I missed that you had a stripped down part.

Comment: @Jared Smith No worries, all gone now sorry about the confusion

Comment: @OmarAlangurli: The example works for me in both Chrome and Firefox.  I suspect there's some crucial detail missing here.  How are you opening the page in the first place?  When you navigate from one page to the next, is the URL origin still the same?  (e.g. `http://localhost`)

Comment: @David that is really weird, maybe its an issue with my firefox specifically? both URLs appear like file:///C:/Users/####/#####/MIT/CWA/assign2/mrenew.html with only the last section changing, (i hashed out some of my details)

Comment: Do not use the file system to develop on. Run a local server! File system has different security constraints.

Comment: @OmarAlangurli: Ah, that's *most likely* the problem.  The behavior may differ by browser, but in general you can expect *a lot* of functionality to simply "not work" when loading pages from the file system.  If you're developing web pages, serve them from a web server.  (Even a locally installed one on your workstation, it doesn't need to physically be a different machine.)  Not only is this more standard and supported, but it *much* more closely approximates the target production environment.

Comment: @David okay thank you i will try that, the only issue is part of the assignments requirement is to ensure the website is functional on firefox, if i test it and develop it with a server, will it run the same on their firefox when they check it? (we do host it on a server when we submit it)

Comment: @OmarAlangurli: There's no way to 100% guarantee that every possible thing will behave the same way in every possible version of Firefox on every possible host.  But in general it's not a problem.